# Regular expression does not match in bash script with variables

Tags: regex, bash

I've tried to use pcre regex matching in my bash script but it never matches even if the string is correct (it should match with "fix #333: test").
What's wrong?

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

REGEXP_PATTERN="(feat|fix|hotfix|refactor|test|docs|chore) (#([0-9]{1,4}))?:(.\S.*)"

# my example is "fix #333: test"
MESSAGE=$(<$1)
if [[ $MESSAGE =~ $REGEXP_PATTERN ]]; then
    echo "match" >&2
else
    echo "not match" >&2
fi
```

it never matches.
any idea?

Comment: [It says](https://ideone.com/2BNA7l) "match"

Comment: even if I set the message to `MESSAGE="fix #333: test"` it returns not match. How is it possible? (macOS 10.15)

Comment: Does it support `\S`? Try `[^[:space:]]` instead.

Comment: Strange... Macs have a really outdated version of bash (3.2, if I recall correctly). However, [`=~` should be supported since version 3.0](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/061). Maybe something changed with the quoting mechanisms. Instead of double quotes, use single quotes to define the pattern: `REGEXP_PATTERN='...'` (because of the `\S`). Then quote the message: `[[ "$MESSAGE" =~ $REGEXP_PATTERN ]]`

Comment: yeah it's bash 3.2.57. I've also tried to make it simplier: `REGEXP_PATTERN='(feat|fix|hotfix|refactor|test|docs|chore)(#([0-9]{1,4}))?:'` and `if [[ "$MESSAGE" =~ $REGEXP_PATTERN ]];` but with "fix #333:" it still not works. It drive me crazy :|

Comment: How are you executing your script? If you source it using `. myscript` or `source myscript` it may run in `zsh` or something different, not bash.

Comment: Add this to your script (`echo $BASH_VERSION`) and add output to your question.

Comment: ```Last login: Sat May  2 19:02:19 on ttys001
daniele@danieleMBP ~ % /.githooks/commit-msg ; exit;
3.2.57(1)-release
not match
```

Comment: the script is a githooks commit-msg. I've also tried double-click it to launch in terminal but it's the same

Comment: It doesn't match on my MacBook with Bash 5 either. I thought the regex engine being used is not part of Bash and can differ from OS to OS. Not using `\S` is probably a good start (try `[^[:space:]]` instead)

Comment: @Socowi The quoting shouldn't make a difference, `"\S"` is still `\S`. But my guess is `\S` just isn't supported by the regex engine.

Comment: Test: `re='\S'; [[ 'x' =~ $re ]] && echo match`

Comment: I was close to writing »*`OP already tried without the \S`*« (see 5th comment). But there was a space missing. Change `…chore)(#…` to `…chore) (#…` and try again.

Comment: Bash regex does not recognize `\S`or `\s` but `[^[:space:]]` or `[[:space:]]`. Also the variable to compare to the ERE must be quoted or it will be space split. So: `REGEXP_PATTERN="(feat|fix|hotfix|refactor|test|docs|chore) (#([0-9]{1,4}))?:(.[^[:space:]].*)"` and `if [[ "$MESSAGE" =~ $REGEXP_PATTERN ]]; then`. Finally use `typeset -p BASH_REMATCH` to debug your Bash RegEx.

Comment: I tested : on MacOS BASH_VERSION 3.2.57 and 5.0.0, `not match` On debian (5.0.3) and Ubuntu (5.0.11) `match`